# Aggregating lambda expressions to form a select query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have a CheckBoxList which holds the names of my columns. In this scenario, the user can select which columns should be displayed in the report. So far I have a method which returns a single lambda expression for each column

```
private Func<viwTechnology, object> LambdaBuilder(string criterion)
{
    switch (criterion)
    {
        case "columnName":
            return (c => { return c.columnName; });
        ....
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

and I call the LambdaBuilder method like this

```
foreach (ListItem item in TableHeadersCheckBoxList.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        lambdas.Add(LambdaBuilder(item.Text)); 
    }
}
```

However I'm having trouble feeding these expressions to my select method. I already have the result I need and I just need to project the columns. I was planning to do something like this:

```
result = (IQueryable<viwTechnology>)result.Select(/*aggregated expression*/);
```

I am not sure how to use the Aggregate<> method of the List neither am I sure about my solution :-??

Comment: You can't, since you don't know what type it'll be.

Comment: @SLaks can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: You don't know what type your lambda returns.

Comment: so how should I solve this problem? can you suggest any other solution?

Comment: That entirely depends on what you're doing with the result.